# Proper data structure to store logical expressions

Tags: python, data-structures, logical-operators

I'd like to store logical expressions properly according to the following sequence:

1. Given a string input such as:

```
term1 / (term2 + term3) +- (term4 + term5)
```

2. This should be translated as:

```
term1 or (term2 and term3) and not (term4 and term5)
```

String processing from step 1 to step 2 won't be a problem here. I'd like to know what should be the proper data structure to store the 'processed' string so that it returns a boolean value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A data structure doesn't *return* something, let be a boolean value. Your desired output suggests that it would be a string, and you also call it the processed string, so there you already determined the data structure (string). Algorithms can return something; data structures only store -- they don't return. Furthermore, is the final outcome you need the boolean? Or is it the "processed" string? If the boolean, why do you need the processed string? So your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear on my question. I want to _store_ this information somehow and write a function to _return_ a  boolean value from the logical expression. Does it make sense?